# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'FIELDNAME' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok I have found people asking similar questions to this but none of them seem to solve my problem.

Basically I am getting the following error in my error log.

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'firstName' cannot be null' in checkoutPayment.php:41
Stack trace:
checkoutPayment.php(41): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
1 {main} thrown in checkoutPayment.php on line 41**

Line 41 is the second to last line of code below which reads...

```
$insertAddressQuery->execute(array_values($addressData));
```

The first part checks all the required checkout fields which are in an array and if they are blank or empty etc it pushes them into a second array.

The second part checks the second array to see if there are any values in it. If there are then some of the required fields must be missing. It should then email me (added this whilst trying to solve the problem) and send the customer back to the basket as I figured that they shouldn't have even got this far if any fields were blank or missing so their session has probably expired.

The third part updates the address (using the session address ID) or inserts a new address if no session address ID exists.

It is this address insert that is causing occasional problems. This doesn't happen all the time and despite putting the email aspect into the code I have had no emails but it has happened twice since in the error log.

Im guessing it has something to do with the "=== NULL" part but I would have received a couple of emails if it was so I just cant seem to solve the error.

```
###CHECK REQUIRED CHECKOUT FIELDS
$requiredCheckoutFields = array('billingFirstName','billingSecondName','billingAddress','billingTown','billingPostCode','billingCountry','billingTelephone','billingEmail','deliveryFirstName','deliverySecondName','deliveryAddress','deliveryTown','deliveryPostCode','deliveryCountry','termsConditions');
foreach($requiredCheckoutFields as $requiredCheckoutField) {
if (($_SESSION['basket'][$requiredCheckoutField]) === NULL) { array_push($requiredCheckoutFieldsMissing,$requiredCheckoutField); }
}

#DECIDE IF TO CONTINUE...
if (count($requiredCheckoutFieldsMissing) != 0) {
    #EMAIL ME AN ERROR
    $emailSubject = 'Checkout Error Report';
    $emailMessage = '<h1>Checkout Error Report</h1>';
    $emailMessage .= '<p>';
    foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $name => $value) { $emailMessage .= $name.'...'.$value.'<br />'; }
    $emailMessage .= '</p>';
    mail($reportEmailAddress, $emailSubject, $emailMessageHeader.$emailMessage.$emailMessageFooter, $emailHeaders);
    #SEND CUSTOMER BACK TO BASKET
    header('Location: basket.php');
}

#UPDATE OR INSERT TO DATABASE
else {
###BILLING ADDRESS
    #UPDATE
    if (isset($_SESSION['basket']['billingAddressID'])) {
        $updateAddressQuery=$dbConnection->prepare("UPDATE orders_addresses SET firstName = ?,secondName = ?,address = ?,address2 = ?,address3 = ?,town = ?,postcode = ?,country = ?,telephone = ?,email = ? WHERE id = ?");
        $addressData = array($_SESSION['basket']['billingFirstName'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingSecondName'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingAddress'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingAddress2'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingAddress3'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingTown'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingPostCode'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingCountry'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingTelephone'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingEmail'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingAddressID']);
        $updateAddressQuery->execute(array_values($addressData));
    }
    #ADD
    else {
        $placeholders = 'NULL,'.str_repeat('?,', 9).'?';
        $insertAddressQuery=$dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO orders_addresses (id,firstName,secondName,address,address2,address3,town,postcode,country,telephone,email) VALUES ($placeholders)");
        $addressData = array($_SESSION['basket']['billingFirstName'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingSecondName'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingAddress'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingAddress2'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingAddress3'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingTown'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingPostCode'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingCountry'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingTelephone'],$_SESSION['basket']['billingEmail']);
        $insertAddressQuery->execute(array_values($addressData));
        $_SESSION['basket']['billingAddressID'] = $dbConnection->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

Comment: var_dump($addressData); before executing the query. Probably, $addressData is empty.

Comment: $addressData is made up of the session values that are checked earlier in the script so is it still possible that $addressData is still empty? Ideally I would stop this way before this point which was the intention of the first part of the code. Thanks

Comment: Did you dump it? It's important to know, where is the issue before we try checking further.

Comment: I can add the var_dump($addressData); line in but I'm not sure what is actually causing the problem and given it doesn't cause the error every time someone goes through that stage of the checkout it might be a week or two before I know if its fixed it. It would seem strange mind if the    " === NULL"   ...line does its job. This is also a live working site and given it is intermittent I'm not sure how I can check it will fix it?

Comment: Most probably, `$_SESSION['basket']['billingFirstName']` is empty or null when you try to insert it. And mysql gives an error.

Comment: That is what I thought but the first part of the script should be checking if any of the required fields are blank, empty, null etc with the "=== NULL" line and if any of them are the visitor should be sent back to the Basket. Most people wont even get to this stage without entering all the required fields as it is a 3 stage checkout process and they cannot get past each stage without entering all the data. Then at this 3rd stage they are checked again so this is what I am trying to figure out, how it can be generating this error in the log file. Again, its doesn't do it all the time strangely

Comment: Instead of `if($_SESSION['basket'][$requiredCheckoutField]) === NULL)` try `if(empty($_SESSION['basket'][$requiredCheckoutField]))` it may be equal to an empty string, and not NULL

Comment: I made the change last night and the error has already been triggered today somehow! Driving me crazy